# Three.js | Imported Blender model is like it's rendered in low quality

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I imported in my Three.js project a gltf model exported from Blender.

I know the model is correct and it is perfectly rendered in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/.

But in my Three.js project it seems to have a worse quality as you can see from these screenshots:

https://ibb.co/qrqX8dF (donmccurdy viewer)

https://ibb.co/71wLDLJ (my project)

I dont know if this can be a problem of lighting or some setting in the renderer object.

This is my renderer and light settings:

```
// renderer
var renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
renderer.setClearColor (0xf9f9f9, 1);
renderer.gammaOutput= true;
renderer.antialias= true;
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// light
var directionalLight= new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.9);
scene.add(directionalLight);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you setup your renderer? Try to use the following lines and see if it gets better: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } ); renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );`

Comment: I did it, but nothing change. I added renderer and light setting to my question.

Comment: From your screenshots, it looks like you're on a high-DPI display, and Don's viewer is showing the model with high DPI while yours is using a lower resolution.  Also your lighting setup looks more washed-out, try moving the light to one side.

Answer (score 3):

> renderer.antialias= true;

It's not valid to set the `antialias` parameter like this. All WebGL rendering context parameters must be applied to the constructor. Do it like so

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
```